# Bad HD video deinterlacing processing

Tags: unity, video, mplayer, hd-video, vdpau

I have Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit with Unity. My system configuration is:

- CPU: Core 2 Quad Q6600 (2.4 GHz)
- RAM: 8192 Mb DDR2 Kingston
- Video: Palit GeForce GTX 260 216 SP, and my screen resolution is 1680x1050.

I also have Window 7 Ulitimate installed, and I can see the same files in Media Player Classic without any horizontal lines.

I've installed vdpau driver, NVIDIA drivers 304.51, and MPlayer 2 (within SMPlayer). I've disabled "Sync to VBlank" option in CCSM (because in other way, by default, MPlayer process use about 50-60 percents of my processor load), tried to swich between different deinterlace options in SMPlayer, used "-vc ffh264vdpau,ffmpeg12vdpau" (without quotes) parameters for MPlayer, switched to "Ubuntu 2D", but, finally, have no results.

Any suggestions? How must I to set up MPlayer?

I also attach screenshots of my SMPlayer's options:

[image]

[Full size](http://img.leprosorium.com/1589674)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One (drastic) change which can help is to disable Compositing completely via xorg.conf:

1. Open the file */etc/X11/xorg.conf* with an [editor using sudo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo), for example by executing this command in a terminal:
   `gksudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

   Note: If the file does not exist yet, you need to create it by following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/106975/2906).
2. Add these lines to the end of the file and save it:

   ```
   Section "Extensions"
       Option  "Composite" "Disable"
   EndSection
   ```
3. Reboot (Alternative: Close all applications and force-restart the X Server itself by executing `sudo service lightdm restart`

Note that this procedure will make your desktop unable to display any kind of transparency or smooth desktop animations.

Comment: Thank you a lot. But I am sad this is the last chance to have nice HD playback is to haven't any effects on desktop.

Comment: Sorry to dig this 3 months old Q&A up. I'm not sure how this solves **deinterlacing** issues. It *does* seem to solve **tearing** (VSync) issues for users. @GuyFawkes: have you actually tried this solution? Perhaps you meant tearing instead of interlacing in your Q?

Comment: Yes, I actuall tried this solution. Tearing is like, as I know, "separated" screen, when one part is from "next" frame and another part is from some different frame. But in my case **whole** screen has some lags, and it can be changed by changing "deinterlace" options in video player settings. So I desire it's deinterlacing bug.